# Cálculo de valor de nodos con hijos en árbol binario en base al valor de sus hijos

Tags: java

Quiero calcular el valor de cada nodo de un arbol binario en base al valor de sus hijos. Ya tengo la asignación del valor para los nodos hoja (los que no tienen hijos). Aca esta el codigo para eso.

```
private void NodoHoja(Nodo root)
{
      if (root != null)
      {
         if (root.getIzq() == null && root.getDer() == null) 
         {
                root.ArrayIsomor[0] = "01";
         }
         NodoHoja(root.getIzq());                
         NodoHoja(root.getDer());
      }
}
```

Pero para los demas nodos no se como hacerlo, ¿alguien me puede ayudar?
Dejo una imagen sobre el problema.

La imagen es solo como referencia, ya que no es un arbol binario,pero en si es lo que quiero hacer.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: bienvenido a StackOverflow. He editado tu pregunta para poner un mejor titulo y redacción ya que tu pregunta no tiene que ver con árboles binarios ni con 0's y 1's. Te sugiero que, en lugar de la imagen completa con textos en inglés, pongas una descripción del problema en español y recortes la imagen para mostrar solo la parte gráfica que ayuda a aclarar cómo se construye un valor de un nodo X. Ojo, que en la imagen hay nodos con más de 2 hijos, y tu implementación parece de verdad ser para un árbol binario, pero la imagen muestra otra cosa.

Comment: Si, el arbol de la imagen no es binario, pero lo quiero implementar a un arbol binario.Coloque esa imagen porque es la unica que encontre sobre eso.

Comment: Creo que haría falta entonces aclarar eso en el texto de la pregunta, ya que causa confusión. De hecho, en mi edición, eliminé la palabra _binario_ de todo el texto, pues el planteamiento del problema (en Inglés) y la imagen claramente mostraba que no era binario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con esta rutina puedes asignar el valor de todos los nodos:

```
private void asignarValor(Nodo nodo)
{
      if (nodo != null)
      {
           if (nodo.getIzq() == null && nodo.getDer() == null) 
           {
                //es una hoja
                nodo.ArrayIsomor[0] = "01";
           }
           else
           {
               String valor = "0";
               if (nodo.getIzq() != null) 
               {
                   asignarValor(nodo.getIzq());
                   valor = valor + nodo.getIzq().ArrayIsomor[0];
               }
               if (nodo.getDer() != null) 
               {
                   asignarValor(nodo.getDer());
                   valor = valor + nodo.getDer().ArrayIsomor[0];
               }
               nodo.ArrayIsomor[0] = valor + "1";
           }
      }
}
```

Debes llamar a la rutina con el nodo raíz del árbol.

Comment: Gracias @jachguate  , funciono.

Comment: @Pedro, me alegra. Te invito a hacer el [tour] para aprender sobre el funcionamiento del sitio. Acá nos gusta diferenciar las mejores respuestas marcándolas como [aceptadas](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Además, puedes [votar](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) por las respuestas a tus propias preguntas aún sin tener la reputación necesaria para tener el [privilegio](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) de votar en las preguntas de otros o las respuestas a esas preguntas. De nuevo bienvenido a StackOverflow.